# How can I get a trial or free version of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way to get a trial or free version of Visual Studio, either Visual Studio 2008 or a previous version?

If so, where can I find it?

Comment: I tried to prettify the question so that it doesn't get closed as spam.  After all, the question itself isn't too bad, just its original presentation.

Comment: Should be re-opened in its new form, perfectly valid question, even if you could find the answer with a search engine easily.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I guess Jeff&Joel wouldn't mind if that search engine provides a link to the answer here at SO ;-)

Answer (score 17):

You can get Visual Studio Express for free - http://www.microsoft.com/express/

Comment: ...as the briefest of searches would reveal...

Comment: thanks for help but how are you give me downvote

Comment: @anirudha: One clicks on the downward arrow left of your question to down-vote it. (SCNR)

Answer (score 7):

On the [Visual Studio homepage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/default.aspx), on the left, is a link:

> 2 . **Get Visual Studio** : [Visual Studio 2008 Trial Version](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=83c3a1ec-ed72-4a79-8961-25635db0192b&displaylang=en)

Which gives you a 90 day trial edition of Visual Studio Professional.

Or a trial version of [Team Suite is available here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=d95598d7-aa6e-4f24-82e3-81570c5384cb).

Obviously these links may change when VS2010 is released.